# Why is there a segmentation dump when using the char pointer str1 instead of str?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, gmp

I use this code to create a Padding RSA function. Unfortunately when replacing in

```
mpz_get_str(str, base, N.get_mpz_t());
cout<<"\n\nLength of k = Modulus in bytes: "<<strlen(str);
```

str with str1 I receive segmentation dump. Why does this happen?

```
int main(const int argc, const char *const argv[])
{
// Check number of arguments
if (argc!=4){
printf("usage: %s [Message] [Exponent] [Modulus] \n", argv[0]);
return 1;
}
char *str;
char *str1="";
int base=10,l;
mpz_t op;

// Receive arguments
const mpz_class m(argv[1]), d(argv[2]),N(argv[3]),message(argv[1]);
mpz_get_str(str1, base, N.get_mpz_t());
cout<<"\n\nLength of k = Modulus in bytes: "<<strlen(str1);

// Calculate RSA
cout<<endl<<RSA(m,d,N);

//TestArea
cout<<"\n\n"<<m;
mpz_get_str(str, base, m.get_mpz_t());
cout<<"\n\nLength of string message in bytes: "<<strlen(str);
cout<<"\n\n"<<str;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors (at least). One you've passed a string literal to mpz_get_str.

```
char *str1="";
mpz_get_str(str1, base, N.get_mpz_t());
```

String literals are not modifiable.

Secondly even if the string literal was modifiable you haven't allocated enough memory to hold your number.

Third error is conceptual. It seems you want to find out the number of bytes occupied by `N`, this code, even when working, won't tell you that.

Here's the code to determine the number of bytes occupied by `N`

```
size_t num_bytes = mpz_size(N.get_mpz_t())*sizeof(mp_limb_t);
```

`num_bytes` will be number of bytes used internally by GMP to store the magnitude of the number `N`.

Answer (score 1):

> If str is NULL, the result string is allocated using the current allocation function (see Custom Allocation). The block will be strlen(str)+1 bytes, that being exactly enough for the string and null-terminator.
>
> If str is not NULL, it should point to a block of storage large enough for the result, that being mpz_sizeinbase (op, base) + 2. The two extra bytes are for a possible minus sign, and the null-terminator.

From https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html

When you pass `str1` to the `mpz_get_str` as it is not `NULL` and this function expects `str1` to point to a buffer with enough space for the result, the segment fault will occur when `mpz_get_str` tries to move data to the supposed buffer pointed by `str1`.

A possible solution would be:

```
vector<char> str1(mpz_sizeinbase (N.get_mpz_t(), base) + 2);
mpz_get_str(str1.data(), base, N.get_mpz_t());
```

Comment: Thank you all!

What is the purpose of +2 in str1(mpz_sizeinbase (N.get_mpz_t(), base) + 2)?

Comment: @user11903678 it is in the documentation and in the text I quoted "`The two extra bytes are for a possible minus sign, and the null-terminator.`".

Comment: Thank you ddecos. One more question: as I'm using  the functions to transform tet in numbers I think I could let the sign byte to the soide. Do you agree, would it be any disdvantages in making this? I mean I will use one extra byte for the end of string but there is no need for sign byte as all lettes are represented on 8 bist as a positiv number?

Comment: @user11903678 what you mean by "tet" and "soide"? I didn't understand what you asked.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. One more question: as I'm using the functions to transform letters in numbers I think I could let the sign byte to the side. Do you agree, would there be any disadvantages in proceeding like this? I mean I will use one extra byte for the end of string but there is no need for sign byte as all letters are represented on 8 bits as a positive number?

Comment: @user11903678 I'm having a hard time trying to understand it. Maybe you should create another question where you can better detail your doubt - if you do link the new question here and I'll try to answer it if I can.